# Filtering 'Where In' Queries by 'Is Not Null' in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am attempting to query a table in BigQuery programmatically, and have a WHERE-IN clause that I would like to support having NULL as the value. Current Query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET.TABLE_NAME WHERE HIT_DATE = 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND ID IN (LIST_OF_IDS);
```

I am wondering if there is a way so that I can query everything from the table for a specific date in the case that the *LIST_OF_IDS* input is *NULL* (The idea being that I want to support choosing between an inputting of a list of ids or return everything if no list of ids are given).

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET.TABLE_NAME WHERE HIT_DATE = 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND ID IN (LIST_OF_IDS) IS NOT NULL;
```

But got this error thrown at me:

```
Syntax error: Expression to the left of IS must be parenthesized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATASET.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE HIT_DATE = 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
AND (ID IN (LIST_OF_IDS) OR LIST_OF_IDS IS NULL);
```

Comment: I want to support the case where if LIST_OF_IDS is null the query will return everything for a specific date. The query you wrote above will return Nothing if LIST_OF_IDS is NULL, correct?

Comment: Aha! Thank you :) That's exactly what I was looking for.